# Is there any compiler option in GCC to check for memory errors at compile time?

Tags: c, gcc

I was compiling this program and the compilation went fine. The moment I executed it, it failed with `free(): invalid pointer` error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *p = NULL;
    if ((p = (char *) malloc((int)sizeof(char) * 100)) == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: unable to allocate memory\n");
        return -1;
    }
    p += 50;
    free(p);    
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled using `gcc -o memtest m.c` command.

Are there any `GCC` compiler options that will give a warning/error/indication about these invalid pointer errors during compile time?

Comment: Most deallocation errors cannot be detected statically.

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:1999 §7.20.3.2 The `free` function says:
_The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` [its argument] to be deallocated, that is, made
available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if
the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the `calloc`, `malloc`, or
`realloc` function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`,
the behavior is undefined._  Since `p + 50` was not returned by `malloc()`, you get undefined behaviour; a core dump is one such undefined behaviour.

Comment: Runtime version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080046/gcc-flags-to-improve-run-time-error-catching Google "static analysis".

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Use [Electric Fence](http://perens.com/FreeSoftware/ElectricFence/) or [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Electric Fence and Valgrind are great, but also work at run time (just like the error that the OP is already getting), not compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

compile time no, runtime - yes:  http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Mudflap_Pointer_Debugging

The closest you may get for compile time is:  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html

Answer (score 1):

No, such errors aren't detected at compile-time because in practice such detection would only trigger for the most trivial cases, like your example.